# Kasa SmartLight Implementation

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am using python to control Kasa light switches using the Kasa and asyncio libraries. I have the basic control of the switches like turning them on and off working.

```
import asyncio
from kasa import SmartStrip
dev = SmartStrip("Ip-address")
test=42
asyncio.run(dev.turn_off())
```

but I need help. As soon as I try to get the lights' status, it always throws an asyncio error, or an error that says `in update children = self.sys_info["children"] KeyError: 'children'` here is the code that i have

```
import asyncio
from kasa import SmartStrip
async def get_device_status():
    strip = SmartStrip("IP") 
    await strip.update()
    status = strip.is_on
    return status

device_status = asyncio.run(get_device_status())
print("Device is on" if device_status else "Device is off")
```

also, ik i will probably get downvoted for this, but I've tried everything i can and this is a last ditch effort. any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the documentation https://python-kasa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/smartstrip.html

hello, I am using python to control Kasa light switches using the Kasa and asyncio libraries. I have the basic control of the switches like turning them on and off working.

```
import asyncio
from kasa import SmartStrip
dev = SmartStrip("Ip-address")
test=42
asyncio.run(dev.turn_off())
```

but I need help. As soon as I try to get the lights' status, it always throws an asyncio error, or an error that says `in update children = self.sys_info["children"] KeyError: 'children'` here is the code that i have

```
import asyncio
from kasa import SmartStrip
async def get_device_status():
    strip = SmartStrip("IP") 
    await strip.update()
    status = strip.is_on
    return status

device_status = asyncio.run(get_device_status())
print("Device is on" if device_status else "Device is off")
```

also, ik i will probably get downvoted for this, but I've tried everything i can and this is a last ditch effort. any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is the documentation https://python-kasa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/smartstrip.html

Comment: Please clean up the description to make it clear what type of devices are you trying to control & what errors you are receiving. If you are trying to control lights, the `SmartStrip` is wrong class for that, and you should be using `SmartBulb` instead: https://python-kasa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/smartbulb.html#api-documentation